# How to display extjs 3.4 grid in icon view

Tags: javascript, extjs

Hi i have extjs grid  in Column Model  currently my grid is appearing normally with rows now i want to display
my gird rows in icon view. .  so what can i do for that ?

also can we take button in tbar with type Xtemplate  so by passing array to Xtemplate Constructor we can overwrite Xtemplate in grid., if it so then how to do that ?

will you please tell me ?

```
    datastore = new Ext.data.Store({  // data store
    ...
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
    ..     
    }),
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
    ...            
    ])),
    }),

    var gridtb = new Ext.Toolbar([  // Tool bar
    {
    xtype: "tbbutton",
    id: 'tb_home',
    icon: '<?php echo _EXT_URL ?>/images/_home.png',
    text: '<?php echo ext_Lang::msg('homelink', true ) ?>',
    tooltip: '<?php echo ext_Lang::msg('homelink', true ) ?>',
    cls:'x-btn-text-icon',
    handler: function() { chDir('') }
    },
    ...

    var cm = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({   // Colum model..
    columns: [  
            {
               ...
               css: 'white-space:normal;'
            }
            ...
    })  

    var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({            //Viewport to display  grid. . in centre region . .
    layout:'border',
    ..
    items: [
    {             
    xtype: "editorgrid",
    region: "center",
    title: "<?php echo ext_lang::msg("actdir", true ) ?>",
    autoScroll:true,
    collapsible: false,
    closeOnTab: true,
    id: "gridpanel",
    ds: datastore,
    cm: cm,
    tbar: gridtb,
    bbar: gridbb,   
    ...
    }
    })
```

Comment: What is icon view? What are you trying to do?

Comment: when you arrange folder in wondows (e.q. Xp) then you can arrange folder by list,deatils,thumbail,icons . . etc. .  so now my grid appears in row view and i want if i click the button then then all rows should be displayed in icons with their thumbnails.  e.q http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/view/multisort-dataview.html see this and consider it as a grid. !

Comment: It looks like you have a good example already then. In the example you gave, it looks like the block of code starting with `var dataview = new Ext.DataView({` is how they render the `store` data as icons.